# Want to show item from another list to a different List view

Tags: xslt-list-view-web-part

I am modifying a view of List A. My view page  is colorcode.aspx and I have one more List B which items need to shown in the View page of colorcode.aspx.

I want to know using xsl:value-of select="" how can I show a item value from List B to the view of List A.

Please help !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT only works with the specific list view that it is applied to so you cannot have a simple xsl:value-of that pulls data from another list.

You could add a second list view to the page and created a relationship between the two views so one would filter the other.

If you want something more customised then you could use jQuery to get data from the second list and inject it wherever you wanted on the page.  In this instance you could create a placeholder using your XSLT and then populate it with the jQuery.

Comment: Hey Dave thanks for your response. Finally i used the jquery to populate the data from another list and its working fine.

Comment: That is great - glad it worked